# Jenkins (hudson) plugin development meet maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1-SNAPSHOT issue

Tags: maven, hudson-plugins, jenkins

I try to develop one jenkins (a.k.a hudson) plugin, and follow the [Tutorial](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial), and generated source code tree after `mvn -cpu hpi:create` command.

While when I do "mvn package", it reports error like

```
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.example.jenkins:redmine2:hpi:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin

Reason: Error getting POM for 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin' from the repository: Failed to resolve artifact, possibly due to a repository list that is not appropriately equipped for this artifact's metadata.
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
 nexus (http://maven.nexus.local:8888/nexus/content/groups/public)

for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin
```

From my nexus server, it has `maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0` version only, but this dependence is generated from jenkins by default, anyone can help me to solve it ?

- (How) Can I change to plugin-1.0 version.
- what can I add in nexus server

I just have basic knowledge of maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by myself by doing two things.

**1.** Added Apache snapshot from [here](http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/) into my nexus repo group besides those setting in [Tutorial](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial)

**2.** It seems my local maven repo is messed up as well, so I can clean it up and reload from nexus.

And it still use `maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT` plugins.

Hope it helps you as well.